# xubuntu app menu on wrong side of screen

Tags: xubuntu, screen, panel, menu

I am using Xubuntu 12.04, with a dual monitor setup (with the nvidia driver xinerama enabled). The top panel is spanned acros the two monitors. This works quite fine, except for one thing.

When I click the little Application Menu button on my left screen, the application menu opens on the top right corner of the left screen.
This is quite annoying, I fiddled in the panel prefs but could not fix this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is to set the panel length to 90 (it was 100).  You could also restrict the panel to a single monitor only.